# Is it idiomatic to say "please always close the door behind you"?

Tags: meaning, idiomatic-language

my sister's bedroom is face to my bedroom and she play music loudly, which is disturbing me. So, I said to her, please always close the door behind you. I would like to have her remember this, and close the door next time without my reminder, close our own doors to avoid disturbing each other.

Is it an idiomatic expression?

Comment: Close-the-doooor! You care to be idiomatic with your sister?

Comment: @Jan Even though I do not need to care about to be idiomatic with my sister, I care about my English L:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Always" may sound more commanding than you want and actually if you are not her boss, it may not be justifiable to say that.

"Behind you" is redundant when it's obvious, so you end up with "Close the door, please."

If she's a decent human being, she'll understand even better if you give here some reasoning: I try to study (sleep, or so), and your music is disturbing me, so would you...? If you have a good reason, you'll find the right words.

Comment: I am pretty sure she is a decent girl. I would like to have her remember this, and close the door next time without my reminder, close our own doors to avoid disturbing each other.

Comment: @WXJ96163, when you say something to your sister, you want to be efficient, convincing, right? So, you may want to think about your _reasons_ why her music disturbs you and tell her with your own words. I do believe your sister is decent, so she should understand. I believe that what you want is not to be idiomatic, but to avoid being commanding or violent, but still be efficient.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. I am trying to have her understand this without being commanding. So, after making that explanation, and then say "always close the door" is it not commanding any more?

Comment: @WXJ96163, "always" is  a spoiler, because she can have her own right reasons why sometimes not to close her door. Even if she's not right. I mean, "always" sounds very commanding. Just go with what you _believe_ is right and then hope it will happen. Often, you can't control people, but you can ask them for a favor.

Comment: How about "close the door for our sake?"

Comment: You say what you _believe_ is good for _you_.

Comment: "Shut that door, will you?"